# python await multiple queues, events, etc

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'd like to await multiple asyncio queues, events, etc. When you have coroutines wrapping futures that are already being fulfilled by other tasks, there is absolutely no point in creating yet another Task. So I'm wondering if anyone is able to get any further than me.

Topics:

- extracting futures from coroutines
- awaiting started coroutines
- modifying coroutine objects

```
async def task(q, e):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task: putting")
    await q.put(10)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task: setting")
    e.set()
    return "done"

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    e = asyncio.Event()

    # Create the task that fulfills the futures
    # backing the coroutines below.
    t = asyncio.create_task(task(q, e))

    # Create the coroutines and extract the futures.
    qc = q.get()
    qf = qc.send(None)

    ec = e.wait()
    ef = ec.send(None)

    # Mapping from future to coroutine so we can resume
    # the coroutine once the future is fulfilled.
    m = {qf: qc, ef: ec}

    print(qf, type(qf))
    print(ef, type(ef))

    pending = {qf, ef}
    while pending:
        # Instruct the loop to resume this task
        # whenever the first future is done()
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        print(done, pending)
        # Now resume the remaining non-blocking code left
        # in the coroutines whose futures are done()
        for f in done:
            c = m[f]
            # *** AttributeError: attribute 'cr_suspended'
            # of 'coroutine' objects is not writable
            #c.cr_suspended = False
            # RuntimeError: coroutine is being awaited already
            v = await c

    await t


asyncio.run(main())
```

This technique manually steps through the coroutine both before and after the future is returned, including any exception handling. It is a cooperative approach that needs to be tweaked depending on the coroutine, such as for ones that return multiple futures. For the standard way of doing things, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903136/2626865) by *Meghshyam Sonar*:

- Create a new task for each coroutine.
- Each task runs the coroutine, returning any (possibly more than one) future to the event loop (note: this is just how `await` works).
- each task captures the return value or exception thrown by the coroutine
- Instruct the event loop to resume the main task when at least one coroutine has completed.

If other tasks are already fulfilling the coroutines' futures, then it is redundant to create yet more tasks just to watch those futures. Who watches the watchmen?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a corrected version of your code that removes the unnecessary task creations and awaits the coroutines directly:

```py
import asyncio

async def task(q, e):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task: putting")
    await q.put(10)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task: setting")
    e.set()
    return "done"

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    e = asyncio.Event()

    t = asyncio.create_task(task(q, e))

    qc = q.get()
    ec = e.wait()

    pending = {qc, ec}
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for f in done:
            if f == qc:
                value = await f
                print("Queue value:", value)
            elif f == ec:
                f.clear()
                print("Event is set")

    await t

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this version, the main change is to directly await the coroutines you're interested in (`qc` and `ec`). This avoids creating unnecessary tasks and correctly handles the queue and event behaviors as intended.

Comment: That's... First, the point of the question is to avoid creating unnecessary tasks, but `asyncio.wait` will automatically create new tasks for every coroutine provided. In fact python 3.11 raises `RuntimeError` when passed coroutines. You see that creating a future to watch a future is redundant? Also, you should fetch the result from the done task rather than getting a second value off the queue, which will block forever.

Comment: Yes that's much better, though it doesn't really answer the question. Note that `asyncio.wait` will still create tasks. From the documentation: *Deprecated since version 3.8: If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task* - for version 3.10.

Comment: Did you tried asyncio.gather

Comment: `asyncio.gather` shares similar behavior: *"If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled as a Task"* - v3.10.

Comment: Considering that you're aiming to avoid this automatic task creation, and you're seeking an approach to directly await multiple asyncio queues and events without unnecessary task wrapping, there isn't a straightforward solution that aligns with your requirement.

To work around this, you might need to use the traditional approach of wrapping coroutines in tasks explicitly. This might be necessary until asyncio provides more explicit control over this behavior in future versions.

Comment: By posting my question here, my hope is that at least some one can work out a solution.